# Unit test (Rspec) cannot update `current_user` in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a unit test of this type -

```
describe "#test_feature" do
  it "should test this feature" do
    sign_in @group_user
    get :get_users, {name: "darpan"}
    expect(@group_user.user_detail.name).to eq("darpan")
    sign_out @group_user
  end
end
```

and function `get_users` is like this -

```
def get_users
  quick_start = current_user.user_detail.quick_start
  current_user.user_detail.update_attribute(:name, "darpan")
  render :json => :ok
end
```

Now, when I run above `rspec`, 
`current_user`'s `user_detail` gets updated(checked with `binding.pry`), but logged in user `@group_user`'s `user_detail` does not get updated. Hence my `expect` fails.

What wrong am I doing in testing this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to reload your resource in RSpec in order to see the change:

```
describe "#test_feature" do
  it "should test this feature" do
    sign_in @group_user
    get :get_users, {name: "darpan"}
    @group_user.reload   # Reloads information from the database
    expect(@group_user.user_detail.name).to eq("darpan")
    sign_out @group_user
  end
end
```